# How to make grills in blender?

Tags: texturing, normal-map, height-map, bump, resolution

I'm following this tutorial on how to put grills on teeth but the artists uses C4D. There is a point where he changed the level of detail to increase the resolution of the image texture to make it the grills look better. How would I go about this in blender?[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Unless you're using some kind of machine learning algorithm which I doubt is integrated in Blender, you can't upscale an image texture like that. You can downscale if you have say a 8k resolution to 4k, but not the other way around. Lost data remains lost. Also please don't post the same question twice. If your question hasn't been answered you can try and improve it instead of posting a new one. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Your nodes set up are not connected in the correct way, if you are new to Blender, i highly recommend you to start with the basics in blender. Here is an image of a basic way to connect nodes.

[image]

And you also need some lights.

Comment: I have no idea what the image textures contain shown in the material setup in the question - so why do you say they are not connected in the correct way? The only wrong thing I can see is that the image texture for displacement is plugged into the normal input of the _Displacement_ node, but it should go into height... and the displacement texture is not set to non-color (which I would recommend, too, but it's not obligatory). Anything else is okay as it is.

Comment: Of course you can add _Texture Coordinate_ and _Mapping_ nodes, but they are not obligatory either. Especially when using the _UV_ output and no changes in the _Mapping_, that's what the other texture nodes use as default setting when there's nothing plugged into the _Vector_ input.